# How to prove that composition of two conformal functions is conformal

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ =$\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$. A theorem from my lecture notes says that a function $f: \hat{\mathbb{C}} \rightarrow \hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is conformal iff f is a linear fractional transformation (that is to say $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}, ad-bc \neq 0$).

Assuming $f ,g:\mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ are conformal, how can we prove that the composite function $f \circ g$ is conformal? Is it enough to state the theorem above?

Finally, is a conformal function the same as an analytic function in some set $U \subset \mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if $$f = \frac{a_1z+a_2}{a_3z+a_4}, g = \frac{a_5z+a_6}{a_7z+a_8}$$
Then their composition is:

$$f \circ g  = \frac{\frac{a_1(a_5z+a_6)}{a_7z+a_8}+a_2}{\frac{a_3(a_5z+a_6)}{a_7z+a_8}+a_4}\cdot\frac{a_7z+a_8}{a_7z+a_8}\\
=\frac{(a_1a_5+a_2a_7)z+(a_1a_6+a_2a_8)}{(a_3a_5+a_4a_7)z+(a_3a_6+a_4a_8)}$$
Which is obviously of the correct form, and $$(a_1a_5+a_2a_7)(a_3a_6+a_4a_8)-(a_1a_6+a_2a_8)(a_3a_5+a_4a_7) \neq 0$$
follows directly from both $ad-bc$ from $f,g$ not being 0.

So yes, their composition is conformal. These classes of functions are what we call [Möbius transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation), and we just proved that composition of two Möbius transformations is another one.

For $\Bbb D$ the situation is a lot easier. Not all analytic functions are coformal, but $$f \text{ analytic with derivative non-zero everywhere} \Leftrightarrow f \text{ conformal}$$

and you know compositions of analytic functions are analytic, and the derivative of $f \circ g$ will also be non-zero everywhere, so the composition of conformal functions on $\Bbb D$ is in fact another.

Comment: So you don't think that domain($\mathbb{C}$) and codomain(range)($\mathbb{C}$) in the "theorem" are irrelevant in proving the claim? In other words theorem works also in unit disk?

Comment: @alvoutila I apologize, I misread your question. I added the correct answer.

Comment: So it doesn't matter whether you have unitdisk $\mathbb{D}$ or whole complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ as domain and codomain in proving the claim when you use theorem in the proof?

Comment: Yes. Because if it is analytic and it's derivative is non-zero everywhere the Lagrange inversion theorem gives an inverse and it satisfies the same properties of analyticity and non-zero derivative. This applies for any subset of $\Bbb C$ as domain and codomain, but it is notably different for $\hat {\Bbb C}$, which requires a Mobius transformation.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't enough to state the above theorem, without knowing that $\Bbb D=\hat{\Bbb C}$. You should be able to prove it directly by whatever definition you have for conformal.

It turns out that an analytic function on $U\subset\Bbb C$ is conformal iff its derivative is everywhere non-zero in $U$.

Comment: any sources for this latest claim? from wikipedia for example?

Comment: [Here you go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map#Complex_analysis).